# Magento upgrade error: Insert value list does not match column list

Tags: php, mysql, magento, pdo

I ran into this problem while upgrading from Magento 1.6.2. Everything was looking great till I made a minor change to system > configuration. After the change I needed to re-index. Re-indexing failed with the error: 'There was a problem with reindexing process.' I have spent most of the evening trying to resolve this issue. I have got almost everything else up and running on a new Magento 1.8 site. I enabled debugging in /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and have included the log below. I don't know what I am missing...

```
## 2014-04-05 06:26:24
EXCEPTION 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement >execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(287): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#15 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(287): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Comment: a wild guess. check if PDO::ATTR_EMULATION_MODE is set to TRUE

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?